# How to make proguard obfuscate enum names?

Tags: java, enums, proguard, obfuscation

First of all I'm far from my development machine.

Let assume I have:

```
public enum Num {
    ONE,
    TWO
}
```

And I have following code:

```
String name = Num.ONE.name();
```

Will name value stay the same after obfuscation? From the `Enum` class code it should stay the same after obfuscation since it happens after compilation when the name string will be generated.

Am I right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189249/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-enum-constants-and-fields ?

Comment: guys, it is not duplicate. I actually want to obfuscate enum names as well, but looks like by default or by some our configuration names are still preserved.

Comment: Related: https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/141/

Comment: @EugenMartynov did you ever find a solution to obfuscate `enum` names?

Comment: how far are you from your machine? 9 inches? 20 feet? 200 yards? 30 miles?