# Release build varient error : java.lang.NoSuchFieldException:

Tags: android

My code works fine with `debug build` varient but whent i try with `release build` it givs me an error  `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException:` for some `enum` value

```
String str = mGson.toJson(obj));
```

I tried so many answers but it did not work 
i have  enum in my progurad rules file

```
 -keepclassmembers enum * {
 public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
 }
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33201546/413127 add `<fields>;`

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: You could sanity check that thats the problem, i.e. write a bit of code in your app that Log's out the enum name. That way it should be kept by proguard anyway. Once you prove that works, you know the problem is your proguard config.